# Toggle class on child elements (and remove siblings)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code, being used to create an accordion effect by toggling an `.active` class. Upon click of `.section-header`, I am toggling a class on both the header and the `.section-content`. This is working well.

However, as mentioned, this is to create an accordion effect, which is amde up of multiple `.accordion-section` `<div>` tags. I need to adjust the jquery in order to remove all `.active` classes from every `.accordion-section` other than the one that is currently active. At the moment, the clicking of `.section-header` toggles an `.active` class on ALL `.section-content` `<div>` tags.

Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="section-header">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </a>
    <div class="section-content">
        <div>Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.accordion-section .section-header').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Can we see your rendered HTML please? Your PHP is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: $('.accordion-section .section-header').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');                                                       
    $('.accordion-section .section-header').not(this).removeClass('active');
});

Comment: Hi @j08691 - have edited the question, thanks.

Comment: I have the following, which works well for .section-header, however it needs work in order to also effect the .section-content within the same div, whilst closing all others?

$('.section-header').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
 $('.section-header').not(this).removeClass('active');
 
 $('.section-content').not(this).removeClass('active');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.accordion-section .section-header').click(function(){
    // Check to see the initial state of the element
    var isActive = $(this).hasClass('active');

    // first remove the active class from all other section headers within this accordion section
    $('.accordion-section')
        .find('.section-header, .section-content')
            .removeClass('active');

    // Get the header and content for this section
    var sectionHeaderAndContent = $(this)
        .closest('.accordion-section')
            .find('.section-header, .section-content');

    // Toggle Active State: Set final active state based on state when clicked
    (isActive) ? sectionHeaderAndContent.removeClass('active'): sectionHeaderAndContent.addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. I need to also toggle the current sections .section-content, any ideas?

Comment: you can pass as many selectors as you want and JQuery will find all of the elements that match the individual selectors. Just change the text in the `find` function from `'.section-header'` to `'.section-header, .section-content'`. You'll also need to set the `.section-content` to active. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry one final thing, when clicking on the same accordion section, the classes are not removed to close the section, can this be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it notifies you when I update an answer or not but this should be what you need.